# Removing Path2D from Rectangle

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I was trying to remove a Bezier curve from a rectangle. I have both shapes, but have a small problem when subtracting Path2D object from Rectangle. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Image Link]

As you can see, I don't want the line at the bottom, under the curve. My code is like this (no need to worry about values):

```
        Path2D path1 = new Path2D.Double();
        path1.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
        path1.curveTo(control1_x, control1_y, control2_x, control2_y, end_x, end_y);
        path1.append(new Line2D.Double(start_x, start_y, end_x, start_y), false);
        path1.closePath();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        Area shape = calculateOutside(path1);

        g2.fill(shape);
```

Also, `calculateOutside` method:

```
    private Area calculateOutside(Path2D path) {
        Area outside = new Area(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
        outside.subtract(new Area(path2D));
        return outside;
    }
```

I also tried with appending line under that curve with `true` as constructor value. Or tried without appending the line. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Also, the values if anyone needs it:

```
        int start_x = 60, start_y = 76;
        int control1_x = 57, control1_y = 49;
        int control2_x = 83, control2_y = 47;
        int end_x = 80, end_y = 76;
```

Comment: A guess: Your `height` is 76, and you're meeting a border case (no pun intended. Oh. Well. Yes. It *was* intended) of the [definition of insideness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness) of shapes. Where do you get your `height` from? If it's also hard-wired, you may fiddle around with a `-1` here or `+1` there...

Comment: It was not hard-wired actually but as you have said, it was about border case. The reason behind that was using integers when calculating the values. Used double and the problem is solved. Thanks!